# Node.js return data to async function fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

After running the code below I get undefined in the console.log.

I am attempting to return a resolved Promise but it fails. There are no errors.

The console output is: getData(): undefined

Can anyone spot my issue?

```
function getData(){
  var url = 'https://pigfox.com/api/v1/test';
  https.get(url, res => {
      res.setEncoding("utf8");
      res.on('data', data => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve(data);
        });
      });
  });   
}

async function go(){
    var rs = await getData();
    console.log('getData(): ' + rs);
}

go();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `await` as "unpacking" a promise. At the moment your `getData` isn't returning a `Promise` and so there is nothing to "unpack". Although you do `return new Promise` within your function, you're actually returning to the inner callback function, not to your outer `getData` function.

So, you need to wrap your `.get` method within a Promise, and resolve the data:

```
function getData() { 
  var url = 'https://pigfox.com/api/v1/test';
  return new Promise(resolve => { // getData returns a promise
    https.get(url, res => {
      res.setEncoding("utf8");
      res.on('data', data => {
        resolve(data); // resolve data which can be "unpacked" using await
      });
    });
  });
}

async function go() {
  var rs = await getData(); // now we can "unpack" the promise
  console.log('getData(): ' + rs);
}

go();
```